# how to use a file input to speech recognition cognitive services

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services

I am using `Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech`.

I have already made it correctly transcribe my voice direct from the microphone, but now I want it to transcribe a file.

I tried

```
using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput(@"/Full/Path/To/File.wav")))
{
    recognizer.Recognizing += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"RECOGNIZING: Text={e.Result.Text}");
    };

    recognizer.Recognized += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
        }
        else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.NoMatch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"NOMATCH: Speech could not be recognized.");
        }
        else if (e.Result.Reason == ResultReason.Canceled)
        {
            var cancellation = CancellationDetails.FromResult(e.Result);
            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={cancellation.Reason}");

            if (cancellation.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={cancellation.ErrorCode}");
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={cancellation.ErrorDetails}");
                Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
            }
        }
    };

    recognizer.Canceled += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Reason={e.Reason}");

        if (e.Reason == CancellationReason.Error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorCode={e.ErrorCode}");
            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: ErrorDetails={e.ErrorDetails}");
            Console.WriteLine($"CANCELED: Did you update the subscription info?");
        }
    };

    recognizer.SessionStarted += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nSession started event.");
    };

    recognizer.SessionStopped += (s, e) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nSession stopped event.");
        Console.WriteLine("\nStop recognition.");
    };

    await recognizer.StartContinuousRecognitionAsync();
}
```

But I never get the file's transcript, the console prints only "Session started" and then exits.

How can I transcribe an audio file with Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech?

Comment: Sorry but that’s unclear: you say you « want it to transcribe a file », so you want to do provide an input file and get speech? Or you want to get a file in the result of an input (audio from mic or audio file) processing?